# iPhone Keychain

Tags: ios, keychain

I can't get the `KeychainItemWrapper` (Apple example) to work. I've added the `KeychainItemWrapper` files to my project and when running it on the phone, an exception is thrown by `SecItemAdd`, saying that one or more parameters were not valid (result code -50). The code triggering the `SecItemAdd` follows:

```
KeychainItemWrapper* wrapper = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"something" accessGroup:nil];
[wrapper setObject:@"this is my password" forKey:@"password"];
NSLog(@"Password: %@", [wrapper objectForKey:@"password"]);
```

What is wrong?

The code can be found at http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/GenericKeychain/index.html

Comment: 13th question - will you *now* accept any?

Comment: You should also break this up into several questions. The SO system cannot track multiple answers to multiple questions in a single thread. You want people to answer 4 separate theory questions as well as debug your code. That's at least 5 separate answers and (1) most people don't have the time or knowledge to answer all 5 and (2) no one will get rep from answering just one of the 5. Not that it appears you accept answers anyway.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this same issue.  You can't put arbitrary keys in the dictionary, you need to use well-defined keys that the SecItemAdd understands.

Try this:

```
KeychainItemWrapper *wrapper = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"password" accessGroup:nil];
[wrapper setObject:@"this is my password" forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
NSLog(@"password: [%@]", [wrapper objectForKey:(id)kSecValueData]);
[wrapper release];
```